# How to display big image notification IOS

Tags: flutter, push-notification, flutter-local-notification, flutter-notification

```
 Future<NotificationDetails> _notificationDetails({String url}) async {
    http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
    const  AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'channel_id',
      'channel_name',
      icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
      channelDescription: 'description',
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.max,
      playSound: true,
      color: Color(0x00000010),
      enableVibration: false,
      //vibrationPattern: 10
    );
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      final image = response.bodyBytes;
      BigPictureStyleInformation androidImage =
      BigPictureStyleInformation(
        ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(base64Encode(image)),
        largeIcon: ByteArrayAndroidBitmap.fromBase64String(base64Encode(image)),
      );
      androidNotificationDetails = AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'channel_id',
          'channel_name',
          icon: '@drawable/ic_launcher',
          channelDescription: 'description',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.max,
          styleInformation: androidImage,
          playSound: true,
          sound: null
      );
    }

    const IOSNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails =
    IOSNotificationDetails(
      badgeNumber: 10,
      presentBadge: true,
      presentAlert: true,
      attachments: [IOSNotificationAttachment('images/account/location.png')]
      //presentSound: true
    );

    return  NotificationDetails(
      android: androidNotificationDetails,
      iOS: iosNotificationDetails,
    );
  }
```

I want to display big image notification like android using flutter_local_notificaion package like youtube or facebook I dont know to use attachment in flutter_local_notificaion  IOS
I want to display big image notification like android using flutter_local_notificaion package like youtube or facebook I dont know to use attachment in flutter_local_notificaion  IOS

Comment: Please check documentation of Firebase Push Notification **(Advanced, Optional) Allowing Notification Images**

Answer (score 0):

[FCM via APNs Integration](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/apple-integration/#advanced-optional-allowing-notification-images)

Please Follow the same Steps of FCM via APNs Integration (Advanced, Optional) Allowing Notification Images

Answer (score 0):

This answer was originally posted on the [flutter_local_notifications close issue](https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1166)

To achieve that, you need to copy/save the file in **"images/account/location.png"** to your application directory and then pass the file path to the IOSNotificationAttachment.

Please follow the link to see a sample code/example.

Answer (score 0):

the whole point is that you need to provide path in your PHONE FILE SYSTEM where the PICTURE is stored,

my example is with downloading picture from the web (implementing it with file from the repo is slightly different but mostly similar)

```
  final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
"https:PICTURE_ADRESS_IN_THE_WEB.jpg"));

  // Get temporary directory
  final dir = await getTemporaryDirectory();

  // Create an image name
  var filename = '${dir.path}/image.png';

  // Save to filesystem
  final file = File(filename);
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);


  DarwinNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails = DarwinNotificationDetails(
      attachments: [DarwinNotificationAttachment(filename)]);
```